# connection <monitor> to 15.200.165.69:27017 timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am getting connection time out error

description:

i am running node js api in docker container and mongodb is running on ec2 instnace with 3 node cluster and attached network load balancer and while running the nodejs api with npm the database is connecting and working fine and while when i ran the same code in docker container the database is not connecting and getting "connection  to 15.200.165.69:27017 timed out" error

below is my docker file :

FROM node-11-alphine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "node", "src/app.js" ]

Comment: How are you launching the container in both environments?  Where does that IP address come from?  If the database is outside your AWS VPC, do you need to configure security groups to allow the connection?  Are there any more relevant details than this Dockerfile that would help explain the setup further?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved

I expose the multiple ports in docker file
for my requirement i expose both 3001 and 27017 ports